# Can a tournament allowed to run if all players are allowed to cheat?

Tags: online-chess

I am interested to know whether money based online chess tournament would succeed if all players are allowed to cheat.

Answer (score 1):

This concept is called [advanced chess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Chess) or [freestyle chess](http://freestyle-chess.webs.com).

There used to be an advances chess tournament in Leon already in the late nineties. Nowadays it has reverted to a normal rapid tournament.

And there have been freestyle tournaments online (for money), first organised by chessbase and nowadays apparently continued by [Infinity Chess](http://freestyle-chess.webs.com/infinitychess.htm).